# Where can I ask questions (career advice) about jobs in Aviation Management?

Tags: aircraft-design, airline-operations, airport

I am thinking of changing my career. I have a physics degree and I want to do a masters in aviation management.Is there any sites where can I get an idea about my chances at getting a job in the aviation management sector, if I do a masters? (with no prior experience).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about locating resources for career advice.

Comment: @kevin I can see your point, but I kind of disagree.  We do cover questions about the operational side of airlines, and getting a job with operations would fit under that (I think).  I'm voting to reopen it, but I'll also open a question on meta to see what everyone thinks.

Comment: The discussion is here: http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/are-questions-about-careers-in-aviation-on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a huge demand for aviation professionals. However, how that demand is looks like is very difficult to answer, since it's a pretty fragmented market and getting an overview is very difficult.

**As such, you're best chances of understanding it are:**

- Going to recruitment fairs that major airlines attend.
- Attending events that airlines hold themselves.
- Trying to get in touch with human resources in an appropriate way directly.

From this you should be to gauge how interesting a candidate you will be. As with most things, this is hardly an exact science. Getting a program with a placement/internship as part of the course for instance might be quite beneficial. As for the no previous experience, I think this is the case for most people heading into this area.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was also wondering, if you know any website especially catered to aviation careers? Maybe I can ask my question there?

Comment: I think you're unlikely to find a forum for this sort of thing. I don't know where you are geographically, but try something along for instance [Lufthansa Careers](https://www.be-lufthansa.com/en/) or their facebook page [be-lufthansa](https://www.facebook.com/BeLufthansa). Should be plenty of others as well. If it's fairly exact/well defined, you can try asking it here as well as a new question.

Comment: thank you! this site was indeed helpful! thank you again for taking the time to reply me :) have a great day ahead!